# EsLint rule for label

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem

[image: My image]

My esLint rules:

```
"jsx-a11y/label-has-for": [ 2, {
      "components": [],
      "required": {
        "every": [ "nesting", "id" ]
      },
      "allowChildren": true
    }],
```

I want just for off this error, or fix, help me please

Error msg: A form label must be associated with a control. (jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control)

JSX code:

```
          <input
                type="checkbox"
                id="checkbox-2"
                className="checkbox__input"
            />
            <label
                htmlFor="checkbox-2"
                className="checkbox__label"
            />
```

Comment: As per documentation, `jsx-a11y/label-has-for` is deprecated and you should remove that rule. The documentation for `jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control` has a section about how to resolve this error: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-associated-control.md  . Did you read it?

Comment: Yes, but no one not worked

Comment: Please add the error message as text to the question so that it is searchable to future users

Comment: @CR7 Please post the JSX code as text, both the original one and the one with the attempt to fix it

Comment: Please post your configuration for `jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control`. If it is similar to the one for `jsx-a11y/label-has-for`, then I believe the issue is that you are requiring input elements to be children of their respective label (`nesting`). If you don't want that behavior then don't enable that option (and generally: make yourself familiar with the rules/options you are enabling. There is no point in using them if you don't know how to resolve the issue).

Comment: Of cource,  i want off it, but error not fixed, i don`t have associateed-control.I try to off with this command jsx-a11y/label-has-for:"off"

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows that  the rule `jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control` is applied so you have it enabled one way or another.  Either way, you are getting the error because you require inputs and labels to be nested *and* have IDs. But in your code they only have an ID, they are not nested. So either nest them or remove the option.

Comment: @FelixKling how i can remove option?

Comment: Open the eslint rule file in your text editor, in line `"every": [ "nesting", "id" ]` click after the comma (`,`) to position the cursor there, press the backspace key until the whole `"nesting",` part is removed, then save the file.

Comment: @FelixKling no working

Answer (score -6, accepted):

So first of all, for off this rule i needed to wrote this: `"jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": "off",`

then i need to off this: `"jsx-a11y/label-has-for":"off",`

And after all i needed to move it at the top of the file because in my case if i don`t move it to the top, my rule not worked.

Comment: I believe instead of "off" you mean 0: "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": 0

Comment: @JWoodchuck "off" and 0 have the same effect when toggling es-lint rules.

Comment: removing the rule is not a solution

Comment: It seems like "Trial and error without understanding" + "Cargo cult or possibly downright fraud". Why do you use ESLint in the first place? You can _uninstall it_ and delete its config altogether. This will off them all.

Comment: hmm. We do switch off some eslint rules sometimes. Either it is switch off for one liner or for the whole file. It's normal practices. Eslint rules for the perfect world. It's like the best practices, which you should follow in order to avoid bugs for sure, but for one reason or another, sometimes they can be dropped. Eslint has a syntax for it: for instance the simple rule: // eslint-disable-next-line no-console and so on for each eslint rule.

Comment: But sure, it is the best to consider to follow the rule at first and if you are 110% sure you have to drop it, then you drop it. And if you dropped it, at the end, you can have surprises, side effects, bugs and etc.

Answer (score 49):

Case 1: You can make input inside label

```
  <label>
      <input type="text"/>
  </label>
```

case 2: use htmlFor

```
   <label htmlFor="first-name">
        First Name
   </label>
   <input type="text" id="first-name" />
```

[you can go through the details of rules through this page:](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/label-has-associated-control.md)

### Edit:

According to docs:

**Case:** The label is a sibling of the control.

```
<label htmlFor={domId}>Surname</label>
<input type="text" id={domId} />
```

Comment: in my code, I had to combine both cases: 1) use input inside label and use htmlFor (It is working just with the tag without any attribute)

Comment: case 2 alone worked for me

Answer (score 32):

I solved it by adding the below lines in my `eslint` file

```
{
    ....
    "rules": {
      "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": ["error", {
        "required": {
          "some": ["nesting", "id"]
        }
      }],
      "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": ["error", {
        "required": {
          "some": ["nesting", "id"]
        }
      }]
    },
    ...
}
```

and `don't forget to restart your local server` after adding those lines.

it's only working when the `label htmlFor(React) or for(HTML)` and `input id` is matched.

```
<label htmlFor="temp-id">Label</label>
<input type="text" id="temp-id" />
```

https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/issues/302#issuecomment-425512505

Comment: This does not show an error when the `htmlFor` and the `id` don't match though.
Is that possible at all?

Comment: it works as charm

Answer (score 3):

If you encounter the ESLint warning `A form label must be associated with a control` it means that your HTML structure for form labels and controls is incorrect. To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the `<input>` element is placed inside the `<label>` element and use the htmlFor attribute with a matching id for the `<label>` tag.

Here's the **correct way to structure your code** ✅:

```js
            <label
              htmlFor="title"
              className="block text-gray-700 stext-sm font-bold mb-2"
            >
              Project Title
              <input
                type="text"
                id="title"
                placeholder="Enter Project title"
              />
            </label>
```

By placing the `<input>` element inside the `<label>` element and associating them with the htmlFor and id attributes, you ensure that assistive technologies and screen readers can correctly associate the label with the input control. This enhances accessibility and ensures a better user experience for all users, including those who rely on assistive technologies.

By following this pattern throughout your form elements, you can eliminate the ESLint warning and ensure that your forms are accessible and usable.

Remember to apply this structure to all form elements in your codebase, and you'll have a more accessible and compliant web application.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just for off this warning you can add the special comment just before the line with the label:

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" />
<>{ /* eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control */ }</>
<label htmlFor="myinput"></label>
```

Here you can find many other ESLint inline comments for disabling rules: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments

Comment: disabling the rule is not the solution

Comment: Nivethan, the author asks: "I want just for off this error, or fix" and my answer explains how to off this error. The fixes mentioned in more popular answers

Answer (score 0):

You can correct the mistake by adding a space like this to your label:

```
<label htmlFor="checkboxForm">
  {" "}
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxForm" />
</label>
```